# How to remove registered/added Listeners?

Tags: java, design-patterns, class-design

Typically interfaces that let you add listeners also include a remove method something like the following.

```
interface SomeInterface {
  addListener( Listener) 
  removeListener( Listener );
}
```

This however suck for several reasons.

- It is possible to pass a Listener that has not yet been removed to SomeInterface.removeListener().
- It is also possible to call
  SI.removeListener() when no Listeners
  haven registered. One should not be
  able to call remove before even doing
  an add.
- It also means one has to keep a handle of both the Listener and the SI reference in order to remove at some later stage.

I have a proposal which I believe works solves the those three problems, however I want to hear from others to learn from their ideas and proposals which might be more elegant than my own solution.

Comment: It is possible to pass a Listener that has not yet been **removed** to **SomeInterface.removeListener()** " It's surely fine, to be able to remove something you hadn't removed yet. Did you mean **added** or **addListener**?

Comment: @Maartinus - thats the entire point, you should not be able to call remove before calling add, it does not make sense.

Comment: If you're arguing that there's a problem worth solving, it might help to post code exemplary of the problem.  If you think you have a solution, post it as a design pattern solving that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My proposal would be to have the AddListener method return an object of type ISubscriptionCanceller with one method: CancelSubscription and possibly a SubscriptionActive property.  This object would contain all information necessary to cancel a given subscription, whether subscriptions are stored in an array, linked list, or some new data structure yet to be invented.  It would naturally be impossible to attempt to cancel a subscription that had not yet been requested, since one would not have the necessary ISubscriptionCanceller to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your problems are real.

Sure you could return an object from `addListener` with a no-arg method to remove that listener. Indeed that would simplify deregistration of complete layers. But I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: Why not ? A classic answer is an ATM, first you enter your pin then you get the option to withdraw money. Having a withdraw money option on the same screen as enter pin is stupid and wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is not so suck as you think, I believe. There are many classes that use this pattern. If you really want you can make removeListener() to return true/false (true if the listener has been really removed) or throw exception (e.g. IllegalStateException) when attempting to remove unregistered listener. But do you really want to do this? What will you perform in case of exception? In most cases it does not matter, so I think that make is simple. Your interface is OK.

You can also add method

`Iterator listeners()`

that returns iterator. So, you can remove listener while iterating using Iterator.remove(). At least in this case you will not be able to remove unregistered listener.

Comment: Your Iterator listeners() is plain wrong. Why would any client of that service ever need to get at the listeners ? The only thing that needs those listeners is the service which needs to fire events whenver.

Comment: The original q was not about how popular the use case is, its asking what is a better way. There are ways to prevent being able to call remove in the first place by the compiler. Remove the removeListesner() method...and think of a nbetter way..

Comment: Think of an ATM, first you enter your pin then you can withdraw money. YOu dont get the withdraw option before you have entered the pin - it just does not make sense...

Answer (score -1):

I think a lot of your underlying assumptions are wrong.  Lets consider the alternative in Java, that removeListener is not a method on the class until a listener has been registered.

1. This isn't possible in Java; Java is not a dynamic language (ignoring reflection)
2. Even if it was possible, as it is in javascript, how would you deal with the fact that you can add listeners of different types?  Do you propose a remove method for each type?

Typically if you pass in a listener that has not been registered to some sort of observing class, the method will do nothing and perhaps return a boolean indicating success or failure.  Which is fine, well understood.  I utterly reject this statement: "It is also possible to call SI.removeListener() when no Listeners haven registered. One should not be able to call remove before even doing an add."

Comment: Im not asking how the problem is solved today, everyone is copying somebody else that does not mean there is not a better solution. Your assumptions #1 & #2 has nothing to do w/ the problem. There is a better way w/ out reflection or similar tricks.